# Running spacy in pyspark, but getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spacy

I have a venv set up and running 'conda list' in cmd window I can see spacy 2.2.4, en-core-web-sm 2.2.5, pyspark 2.4.5 among other packages.

I want to apply spacy's named entity recognition to a column in a Spark Dataframe called 'tweets' within Jupyter Notebook. I am doing this by passing the NER into a Spark UDF, and passing that UDF into the withColumn operation:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def spacy_ner(text_col):
    entities = []
    for parsed in nlp.pipe(text_col):
        if parsed.ents:
            inner = ''
            for ent in parsed.ents:
                inner += ent.text + ''
        else:
            inner = ''
        entities.append(inner)
    return entities

ner = udf(spacy_ner)
ner = sqlContext.udf.register("ner", spacy_ner)

tweets = tweets.withColumn('text_ner',ner('text_nosw'))
result = tweets.groupBy(tweets.text_ner).count()
result.show()
```

However I'm getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'":

```
 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1006.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 43.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 43.0 (TID 289, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 366, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 241, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 168, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 71, in read_command
    command = serializer.loads(command.value)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 587, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 366, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 241, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 168, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 71, in read_command
    command = serializer.loads(command.value)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 587, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-9fbae11f2e36> in <module>
      4 tweets = tweets.withColumn('text_ner',ner('text_nosw'))
      5 result = tweets.groupBy(tweets.text_ner).count()
----> 6 result.show()

~/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    378         """
    379         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 380             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    381         else:
    382             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

~/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1006.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 43.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 43.0 (TID 289, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 366, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 241, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 168, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 71, in read_command
    command = serializer.loads(command.value)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 587, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 366, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 241, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 168, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 71, in read_command
    command = serializer.loads(command.value)
  File "/Users/Noah/anaconda3/envs/pyspark_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 587, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this. It appears that I needed to restart my Spark session in the end, so I close this. I don't really understand what was happening, but it's not an open issue anymore.

Comment: I'm a bit of a PySpark newbie, hope you don't mind: what exact command or setting did you run to _"restart your Spark session"_? I'm using PySpark 2.4.8, and what I've done is using this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.stop.html , but I am no quite sure if it is correct or not. Could you please add more details in your answer?